# ADFS authentication CODE for getting acces token

Tags: post, oauth, oauth-2.0, adfs, adfs3.0

ADFS 2012 has one URL to get CODE, and with that CODE, we can call another URL to get access_token.

//get code
1. First call - POST (client_id, redirect_uri, resource, response_type = code), Body (username, password, authmethod)
2. Second call - /token

What is the best aproach when calling from mobile application?

1. Do I need redirect user in web view to login on server and get CODE
2. Create on mobile app form for username and password, and do a call in background - it returns HTML of page (parse it and get CODE)...but, currently I can't get CODE, constantly getting login error

Answer (score 0):

For mobile, the nest way is to use one of the [ADAL libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries).